# Copying processes in Linux

Tags: linux, process

I would like to make a copy of process (On Linux). 
Let say that I have an application that on startup makes lot of calculations, and that takes it a long time. 
I want to start this application few times and don't want to wait.
Thing I would like to do is stoping (not killing) one instance of process after it made all calculations and when I need another instance of it, make a copy and run it.

Is something like that possible?

Comment: if what you want is to have one instance run at a time, then consider suspending and resuming that process. If you want to replicate it into multiple instances running at same time, duplication may cause those instances misbehave.

Comment: I want to have only one instance working at same time, but, let say that program crash often and when it does, I would like to run it from point when it was fully started.

I would like to have a suspended process of fully started program (after it did all calculations at start) and when I need, copy it and resume copy. (So if it would crash, I could do it again)

Comment: Are you creating the application yourself? Could you possibly make use of the `fork` system call? This is how new processes are generally created in Linux. The forked child process is an exact duplicate of its parent process, just with a different PID.

Comment: No, I'm not creating app at my own. (The question is a little hyphotetical). I thought about fork before but, if I'm thinking correctly, it can be used only in application code, that i have not.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it's not currently possible to do this natively in Linux. It might become possible in the future (e.g., when [LXC checkpointing](http://lxc.sourceforge.net/man/lxc-checkpoint.html) is implemented).

In the meantime, if it's feasible to run your application in a virtualized environment, at least some hypervisors support taking snapshots of a running system. For example, [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) is free and has that capability.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using VirtualBox already. I just was thinking, if it's possible to just copy the proccess. Thanks for link, it's quite interesting.